# Numerical methods in python and implementation for constructing a solid

Tags: python, methods, 3d, geometry, numeric

I've started a project with one of my professors on the topic of Johnson solids, and at the moment I am tasked with creating a code that can correctly give me the coordinates of its vertices on an xyz plane for this specific one; J-84 (snub disphenoid) with edge length of 1 unit.

Being a novice in coding, I am quite lost on how to approach the problem and specifically what python tools I should be using to assist me. I have thought about first creating a code that can correctly give me the points of an equilateral triangle on an xy plane, and then extending it to construct a tetrahedron on a xyz plane, and after I understand how all that works, try to apply it to J-84.

For algorithms, I was thinking about using numerical methods such as the conjugate gradient for optimizing a given function that in the end will give me the coordinates of the vertices, but don't know how viable it is to do so in python.

Is there a way to make python plot the points on a 2D or 3D plane? If so, how do I do it? Is implementing a numerical method for optimizing functions a bad idea in python? Or is using a geometrical or analytical argument better? What should I be studying/looking into that could possibly help me?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.